# I am having problems with Typescript property initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am making an Spring and Angular web app, and I have problems with it that appear in the browser inspect mode like: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name').`

I suspect that the problem lays in the property initalization.
(This is the app.component.ts)

```
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  [x: string]: any;
  public employees!: Employee[];
  public editEmployee!: Employee;
  public deleteEmployee!: Employee;
```

My whole project doesn't have any runtime errors, but the app isn't working properly. As it is a employee manager app it has an update delete and add function, and the update isn't working at all and also the add isn't the working properly.

Here is my app.component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;">Employee Manager</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" (click)="onOpenModal(null!, 'add')">Add Employee <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
         <input type="search" (ngModelChange)="searchEmployees(key.value)" #key="ngModel" ngModel
          name="key" id="searchName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search employees..." required>
      </form>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="container" id="main-container">
 <div class="row">
   <div *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
      <div class="card m-b-30">
         <div class="card-body row">
            <div class="col-6">
               <a href=""><img src="{{employee?.imageUrl}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-60"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 card-title align-self-center mb-0">
               <h5>{{employee?.name}}</h5>
               <p class="m-0">{{employee?.jobTitle}}</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>{{employee?.email}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Phone : {{employee?.phone}}</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="float-right btn-group btn-group-sm">
               <a (click)="onOpenModal(employee, 'edit')" class="btn btn-primary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
               <a (click)="onOpenModal(employee, 'delete')" class="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Add Employee Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="addEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addEmployeeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="addEmployeeModalLabel">Add Employee</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddEmployee(addForm)">
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" ngModel name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email Address</label>
              <input type="email" ngModel name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Job title</label>
              <input type="text" ngModel name="jobTitle" class="form-control" id="jobTile" placeholder="Job title" required>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Phone</label>
              <input type="text" ngModel name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Image URL</label>
              <input type="text" ngModel name="imageUrl" class="form-control" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL" required>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="add-employee-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
           </div>
           </form>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 
 <!-- Edit Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="updateEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="employeeEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateEmployeeModalLabel">Edit Employee {{editEmployee.name}}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form #editForm="ngForm">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editEmployee.name}}" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" ngModel="{{editEmployee.id}}" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Email">
               <input type="hidden" ngModel="{{editEmployee.employeeCode}}" name="userCode" class="form-control" id="userCode" placeholder="Email">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                  <input type="email" ngModel="{{editEmployee.email}}" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Job title</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editEmployee.jobTitle}}" name="jobTitle" class="form-control" id="jobTitle" placeholder="Job title">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editEmployee.phone}}" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Image URL</label>
                  <input type="text" ngModel="{{editEmployee.imageUrl}}" name="imageUrl" class="form-control" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL">
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                  <button (click)="onUpdateEmployee(editForm.value)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Delete Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="deleteEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModelLabel">Delete Employee</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete employee {{deleteEmployee.name}}?</p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
               <button (click)="onDeleteEmployee(deleteEmployee.id)" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Notification for no employees -->
 <div *ngIf="employees?.length == 0" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
 <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
   <h4 class="alert-heading">NO EMPLOYEES!</h4>
   <p>No Employees were found.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve the property initialization problem(if it is that at all). Do I maybe downgrade the Angular version, I have tried the to set the StrictPropertyInitalization to false, but it doesn't do much. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: The course that showed this, didn't have to put "!" in the property initalization, and their app works perfectly. So I am suspecting that.

Comment: Your `employees` array most likely contains `undefined`.

Comment: Could you show where you do the initialization (probably the constructor)? A line like `public editEmployee!: Employee;` tells typescript "trust me, i initialize it somewhere else", but it doesn't actually initialize it

Comment: If I do that i have an error in the code:  public searchEmployees(key: string): void {
    console.log(key);
    const results: Employee[] = [];
    for (const employee of this.employees) {
      if (employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      || employee.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      || employee.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      || employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        results.push(employee);
      }
    }
    this.employees = results;

Comment: I have an constructor: constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

Comment: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name"` just an idea of standard Angular property binding... don't know if Spring will make the ngModel be expected to be empty

Comment: What do you imply me doing?, Refactor ngModel to [(ngModel)] ?

Comment: I see on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web that the way to tell Angular to bind the property to the Input tag is the standard way. So, yes, you should try to bind properly the properties in your model using [(ngModel)]="the_property_to_be_bound" in each case.

Comment: Me doing that just gets me a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the object from which you are trying to read the property .name is not yet initialized by the time the template is rendered.

I have sort of re-created something similar to what your project is like, and managed to remove the errors just by using *ngIf before using the object on the template.

Check what I did locally, in case it helps you:

app.component.html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;">Employee Manager</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" (click)="onOpenModal(null!, 'add')">Add Employee <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input type="search" (ngModelChange)="searchEmployees(key.value)" #key="ngModel" ngModel name="key" id="searchName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search employees..." required>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" id="main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="card m-b-30">
                <div class="card-body row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <a href=""><img src="{{employee?.imageUrl}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-60"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 card-title align-self-center mb-0">
                        <h5>{{employee?.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="m-0">{{employee?.jobTitle}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>{{employee?.email}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Phone : {{employee?.phone}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="float-right btn-group btn-group-sm">
                        <a (click)="onOpenModal(employee, 'edit')" class="btn btn-primary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
                        <a (click)="onOpenModal(employee, 'delete')" class="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add Employee Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addEmployeeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addEmployeeModalLabel">Add Employee</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddEmployee(addForm)" *ngIf="editEmployee">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Job title</label>
                            <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.jobTitle" name="jobTitle" class="form-control" id="jobTile" placeholder="Job title" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.phone" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Image URL</label>
                            <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" class="form-control" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="add-employee-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Edit Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="updateEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="employeeEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateEmployeeModalLabel">Edit Employee <span *ngIf="editEmployee">{{editEmployee.name}}</span></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form #editForm="ngForm" *ngIf="editEmployee">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.id" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="hidden" ngModel="editEmployee.employeeCode" name="userCode" class="form-control" id="userCode" placeholder="Email">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Job title</label>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.jobTitle" name="jobTitle" class="form-control" id="jobTitle" placeholder="Job title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.phone" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Image URL</label>
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editEmployee.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" class="form-control" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                            <button (click)="onUpdateEmployee(editForm.value)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Delete Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModelLabel">Delete Employee</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="deleteEmployee">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete employee {{deleteEmployee.name}}?</p>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                        <button (click)="onDeleteEmployee(deleteEmployee.id)" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Notification for no employees -->
<div *ngIf="employees?.length == 0" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <h4 class="alert-heading">NO EMPLOYEES!</h4>
        <p>No Employees were found.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'conSpring';
    employees: Array<Employee> = [];
    editEmployee!: Employee;
    deleteEmployee!: Employee;

    public onOpenModal(a: any, b: string): void {
    }

    public onAddEmployee(a: any): void {
    }

    public searchEmployees(a: any): void {
    }

    public onUpdateEmployee(a: any): void {
    }

    public onDeleteEmployee(a: any): void {
    }
}

export class Employee {
    id!: number;
    employeeCode!: string;
    name!: string;
    jobTitle!: string;
    email!: string;
    phone!: string;
    imageUrl!: string;
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Of course, for me it shows something not usable, because I'm missing the data coming from the back-end and the connection to get it, which you should have (I believe).